# Postgres connections not closing - Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am using PostgreSQL for my web application. I have put session.close in each Hibernate call in application code. But postgres connections are not closiing which makes the application to break after the connection count reahes the threshhold. I need to restart my postgres service to get it up again.

Using Apache Tomcat as webserver.

How can I solve this? Please suggest a permanent fix.

Code snippet below :.

```
session = sessionFactory.opensession(); 
Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction(); 
finally{
   if(session != null) session.close();
}
```

Comment: add you code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the connection pooling or directly connecting through the Hibernate to database? If you are using it through connection pooling than please check the configuration over there once. And If you could post some piece of your code than it will be easy for us to debug and find the issue.

Comment: I am directly connecting from Hibernate to database. Code snippet below :.   ```session = sessionFactory.opensession(); Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction(); ------- finally{if(session != null) session.close();}```

Comment: Can you share the part of code where you have configured the database details

Comment: We're using multi tenancy approach